# How to know if I send data successfully on parse (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I put data on parse server, how could I know if it is successful or not ?

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseObject send = new ParseObject("Class");
    send.put("user", currentUser);
    send.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject send = new ParseObject("Class");
send.put("user", currentUser);
send.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.i("mt app", "You have successfully saved you data in parse");
        } else {
            Log.i("mt app", e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check it There are 2 types of saveinbackground methods are available in Parse. One with a callback and one without callback.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject send = new ParseObject("Parse Class");
send.put("user", currentUser);
send.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e==null)
        {
            done with out error
        }
        else
        {
            issue while saving
        }
    }
});
```